# Print strings as pointers in lldb

Tags: c, lldb

Here's a snippet from a session with lldb:

```
* thread #1, name = 'so', stop reason = breakpoint 5.1
    frame #0: 0x000000000040113c so`test(hello="Hello, world!") at so.c:5:18
   2
   3    void test(char* hello)
   4    {
-> 5      printf("%s\n", hello);
   6    }
```

In the `frame #0` line the argument to the C function `test` is displayed as a string. How can I set things so that all arguments of type `char*` are displayed as pointers by lldb, not strings?

I did read some of the documentation for [`type summary`](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html) but I couldn't see how to apply it to all uses of the type `char*` (and when I did try, my syntax was apparently so unparsable that lldb crashed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a couple of things.  You can disable the category this summary belongs to, which fortunately doesn't have that much in it.  You can find which summary that is that if you have char * pointer handy by doing:

```
(lldb) type summary info my_ptr
summary applied to (char *) my_ptr is: `${var%s}` (skip pointers)
```

Then do `type summary list` and you'll find the one with that summary string:

```
-----------------------
Category: system
-----------------------
OSType: `${var%O}` (not cascading) (skip pointers) (skip references)
^(unsigned )?char ?(\*|\[\])$: `${var%s}` (skip pointers)
^((un)?signed )?char ?\[[0-9]+\]$: `${var%char[]}` (hide value) (skip pointers)
```

So then:

```
(lldb) type category disable system
(lldb) v my_ptr
(char *) my_ptr = 0x0000000100003fa0
```

and you can turn it back on again when you need to.  You can also override the built in summary.  You can see the regular expression string in the output above, so something like:

```
(lldb) type summary add --summary-string ' ' "^(unsigned )?char ?(\*|\[\])$" -x
(lldb) v my_ptr
(char *) my_ptr = 0x0000000100003fa0
```

This should also work:

(lldb) type summary delete "^(unsigned )?char ?(*|[])$"

but because we are deleting the summary we try to be a little careful.  With no options, this command will only delete summaries from the "default" category - where user summaries go when you don't specify a category.  That keeps you from accidentally deleting built-in summaries.

To delete the char * one from the system category, you have to do:

```
(lldb) type summary delete -w system "^(unsigned )?char ?(\*|\[\])$"
```

Comment: Thanks! Your first method is probably OK for my needs for now. Your second method works fine with the `v` command but char* pointers dosn't get printed correctly when I do a `frame select` (say).

Comment: Yes, it looks like someone made the choice that if there is a summary, only the summary will print when rendering the frame format token `function.name-with-args`.  I can see the utility in that, though it causes problems here.  
You could have the summary echo the value but then it would print twice in `v`.  If you get really desperate you can make a python frame format token and return just the pointer value there.  That's all described in: https://lldb.llvm.org/use/formatting.html

Comment: It may be easier to change the type of my own function - the char* is just a pointer to bytes in memory, and I want to see the address when debugging, so I can probably make it a void* :)

Comment: Note I changed the answer to show how to actually delete the built-in summary.  With that you should just see pointer values for anything that matches that regular expression (including char *)...